# Polymorphism: Adding new attribute (Python)

Tags: python, polymorphism

I'm still studying polymorphism in python.
I tried to add color attribute based on this [code](https://www.pythonprogramming.in/polymorphism-in-python.html), but I failed.
Here is my code:

```
class Shape:
    width = 0
    height = 0
    color = 0
 
    def area(self):
        print('Parent class Area ... ')
    
    def get_color(self):
        print('Parent class Color ...')
 
 
class Rectangle(Shape):
 
    def __init__(self, w, h, c):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.color = c
 
    def area(self):
        print('Area of the Rectangle is : ', self.width*self.height)
    
    def get_color(self):
        print('Color of Rectangle: ', self.color)
 

class Triangle(Shape):
 
    def __init__(self, w, h, c):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.color = c
 
    def area(self):
        print('Color of Rectangle: ', self.color)
        print('Area of the Triangle is : ', (self.width*self.height)/2)

    def color(self):
        print('Color of Triangle: ', self.color)
```

Result:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm still newbie in this part. Thank you for your helps before ;)

Comment: you are not showing which statement raises the `TypeErros`.. but I suspect this: your classes cannot have variables and methods with the same name, for example `color´

Comment: Yes, I just realize that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Triangle` class, you have a method named `color` and also a property named `color`.
Change the `color` method to `get_color` it will resolve your problem.

```py
 def get_color(self):
        print('Color of Triangle: ', self.color)
```

The python thinks you are calling the property named `color` which is a `string` and it cannot be called.